# Cleanup for low-usage tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a number of tags with very few questions, and a steady stream of new tags coming in. I don't suggest that this is entirely a bad thing, but too many similar tags makes things hard to find.

I suggest the following tag synonyms would be helpful, there may be others worth combining as well:

---

finance -> money

fish -> plants & animals

calf -> plants & animals

serpent -> plants & animals

charismatic -> spiritual-gifts

evil -> sin

messiah -> messianic prophecy (a fit based on the content of the one "messiah" question)

I see that Steve has also proposed messianic -> messianic prophecy

---

If you think these are helpful, please vote them up, if not, vote 'em down.

PS can we either remove the "lips" & "body" tags, or make them part of the "anatomy" tag?  I don't have the tag rep to propose this one.

Comment: Most of these make sense. I wouldn't want a rule that says all animals should be lumped in though - "sheep" would probably warrant a tag of its own. I'm not sure about "serpent" so I won't act on that. And evil and sin are distinct enough too.

Comment: @curiousdannii good observations, thanks. I also added judgment -> judgement as a proposal